# Can .vimrc be divided into multiple files?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Say I have some hundred custom re-mappings with `iab` for Java and some other hundred or so re-mappings for Haskell, then I'd want do divide these into different files to make it more manageable. What I'm looking for is to create something like this:

```
~/.
 ├── .vimrc
 └── .vim
     └── custom
         ├── java.vim
         └── haskell.vim
```

Where .vimrc might look something like

```
import java
import haskell
```

Is something like this possible to do, or am I just overcomplicating things? I guess what I am trying to achive is what one does in LaTeX with the `\input` command...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't put these in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/$language.vim`?

Comment: Not really, should I? What is supposed to go in `after/ftplugin`?

Comment: If you write a file called, e.g., `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/java.vim`, it will automatically be run whenever you open a `java` file. This seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for ftplugins. This is their purpose.

And don't forget to define your mappings, setting, abbreviation, commands, ... as local. Otherwise they'll parasite other buffers once loaded.

Here are some more complete answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413285/multiple-autocommands-in-vim/1414845#1414845
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825032/vim-inoremap-for-specific-filetypes/8826323#8826323
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404515/gvim-and-multiple-programming-languages/1404570#1404570

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the vim command you're looking for is [`:source`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#using-scripts) or [`:runtime`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#using-scripts) to pull them from `runtimepath`.

For example, you could do this in your `.vimrc`:

```vim
runtime custom/java.vim
runtime custom/haskell.vim
```

presuming `~/.vim` is in your `runtimepath` (which it is by default).

You could also drop your scripts in the `~/.vim/plugin` directory; see [write-plugin](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#41.11) in the docs. Vim automatically runs all the scripts in the plugin directory.

Comment: Cool. Is there any naming convention for what I've here called `custom`, which is not quite plugins but rather files that could as well have been in `.vimrc`?

Comment: @Lindh-E Not that I'm aware of. You probably want to use something that you're sure won't be given meaning by a future vim version. Since they strive to stay compatible with 8.3 file names, I'd suggest a directory name >8 characters.